# Sql Server Full Backup Duration Increased Dramatically

Tags: sql-server-2008, performance, query-performance

since last week My Full Backup Increased dramatically .before last week the time is about 3 hour and now the time is about 6 hour.in addition some query take long time to run.
(not all the query).I thought the problem is relate to disk I/o.
and I try to copy/past some files from one hard drive to another and it is done very quickly.(3 giga byte in 4-5 sec).and all the query work with temp table slow down.
is it relate to I/o or what..?

Comment: i found the solution.the network admin defrag Disk that cause Database fragmentation.by defrag databases the problem is gone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the solution.the network admin defrag Disk that cause Database fragmentation.by defrag databases the problem is gone